# Ctrl+6 not an editor command in Vim (switch language in the .vimrc)

Tags: vim

I want VIM to start with two keymappings by default (Greek and Latin) but the default to be latin for coding. I have managed to add Greek in the .vimrc with `:set keymap=greek`, however that leaves Greek as the default language. Within VIM, I can change into latin in insert mode with Ctrl+6 but I want that to happen automatically when vim is fired up so latin will be the default keymap. The problem is Ctrl+6 (or Ctrl+^) is not an editor command but a key binding and as a result I cannot put it in the .vimrc. Any ideas on how to go around this issue?

tl;dr I want Greek keymap to be loaded automatically in vim but not be the default keymap.

Comment: `not be the default keymap` This is the default. `:verbose set iminsert?`

Comment: If either answer below was of any help to you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting, as appropriate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the solution you're asking for, but a close one that works for me.

I have two `imap` commands in my `.vimrc` to switch between my French and English keyboards:

```
imap ^f <ESC>:set keymap=canfr<CR>a
imap ^^ <ESC>:set keymap=<CR>a
```

In insert mode, if I enter ^f it switches to French, and if I enter ^^ it switches back to the default.

You can also add the same in command mode:

```
map ^f :set keymap=canfr<CR>
map ^^ :set keymap=<CR>
```

In your case, you would have to replace my `:set keymap` command by what you need to activate your respective keyboards, and maybe also replace my `^f` and `^^` by your preferred char, `Ctrl-6` (not sure how to code it, I leave that to you) and a second character of your choice to pick which keyboard.

PS: to create the `ctrl-6` rule, I would hit Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-6 on my keyboard. On one of the too many machines I use, the result looks like this, where I added `e` for English, and `f` for French, but it will most likely be different on yours:

```
map <ESC>[54;5ue :set keymap=<CR>
map <ESC>[54;5uf :set keymap=canfr<CR>
imap <ESC>[54;5ue <ESC>:set keymap=<CR>a
imap <ESC>[54;5uf <ESC>:set keymap=canfr<CR>a
```

I've also replaced the literal escape character that technique produced, which visually looked liked `^[` but was actually just one character, by `<ESC>`, so this can be cut-and-pastable.

PPS: what Ctrl-6 will look like when you hit Ctrl-V Ctrl-6 is highly system dependent. What I showed above was from a ubuntu session in a cygwin-mintty terminal from a Windows machine. In gvim for Windows, it's a single character that displays as `^^`, in vi inside Git Bash, it's a single character that displays as `^?`. The encoding of Ctrl-*N* varies wildly, for reasons I don't fully understand.

PPPS: for all this to work for you, you'll probably have to remove your existing key binding for Ctrl-6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I got this from, but I get the behaviour you want with this:

```
set keymap=greek_utf-8
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=-1
```

Latin is the default and you switch between Greek and Latin with ctrl+6 in insert mode.